# Accessing c++ maps using a different class than the index

Tags: c++, stl, associative-array

Suppose you have a class:

```
class SomeClass{
   public:
      int x;
      SomeClass(){
         x = rand();
      }

      bool operator<(const SomeClass& rhs) const{
         return x < rhs.x;
      }

};
```

And then you have this:

```
map<SomeClass, string> yeah;
```

Obviously this will work:

```
yeah[SomeClass()] = "woot";
```

But is there a way to get something like this:

```
yeah[3] = "huh";
```

working? I mean, I tried setting operator<(int rhs) in addition to the other operator, but no dice. Is this possible at all?

Comment: What is "3" supposed to mean in that context?  The 3rd item in the map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map`'s `[]` operator only takes the templated class as its parameter. What you want instead is some way of generating a specific instance of your class that has the values you want. In this example, add a constructor that lets you specify the value `x` should have.

```
class SomeClass{
   public:
      int x;
      SomeClass(){
         x = rand();
      }
      SomeClass(int a) : x(a){
      }

      bool operator<(const SomeClass& rhs) const{
         return x < rhs.x;
      }

};
```

And then use

```
yeah[SomeClass(3)] = "huh";
```

Or you can just use

```
yeah[3] = "huh";
```

which does the same thing, calling `SomeClass`'s constructor implicitly.

Comment: Since the constructor isn't tagged "explicit", it isn't necessary to invoke it for the map index.  yeah[3] = "huh"; is sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

Add a constructor:

```
SomeClass(int y){
    x = y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can't** use yeah[3] as **this will require the map to store keys of both *SomeClass* and *int* type**;
Also, consider that each time you add a new element to the map, the "indexed" position of a certain element can change, as the elements are always mainteined ordered by the key element.
If you need to look at a certain point in time for the element no j, you can use probably use an iterator on the map.

Comment: The compiler will try and convert an int to SomeClass if there is an available conversion. One of these conversions would be a one argument constructor on SomeClass would be used (if it was defined).